# print form on the full page instead of a part of it

Tags: c#

i want to print my form on the whole page but instead the picture looks like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSXh2.jpg

it looks very small that's why i need the form to be printed on the whole full page

here is my code :

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureScreen();
        printDocument1.Print();

    }

    private Bitmap _memoryImage;

    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        // put into using construct because Graphics objects do not 
        //  get automatically disposed when leaving method scope
        using (var myGraphics = CreateGraphics())
        {
            var s = Size;
            _memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
            using (var memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(_memoryImage))
            {
                memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Location.X, Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
            }
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {



        var wScale = e.MarginBounds.Width / (float)_memoryImage.Width;
        var hScale = e.MarginBounds.Height / (float)_memoryImage.Height;

        // choose the smaller of the two scales
        var scale = wScale < hScale ? wScale : hScale;

        // apply scaling to the image
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

        // print to default printer's page
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_memoryImage, 0, 0);

    }
```

your help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to print in Landscape format?

Comment: You'd better keep it this way.  There's nothing pretty about every pixel in your form getting blown up to a 6x6 blob of ink on paper.  The result looks very grainy, text looks particularly poor.

Answer (score 0):

try this to make a bitmap of your form:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(f1.Width, f1.Height);
this.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(f1.Location, f1.Size));
```

maybe that's the problem! Report back if it works!
If you want to print it in landscape format than you have to rotate your bitmap using:

```
public Bitmap rotateInternalFunction(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: where should i put this ?

Comment: @u Replace the Content of CaptureScreen by the first code block. And u can just use the second one in yourprintDocument1_PrintPage function